# Testcafe request event requestOptions is undefined in custom request hook?

Tags: javascript, testcafe

I'm trying to create a custom request hook that modifies the `Referer` header on my outbound requests for my Testcafe tests. I have followed the docs as well as examples found here, but I'm running into an issue where the `requestOptions` property, that I'm supposed to use to set the header, is undefined on the event that comes into the hook. I'm completely stumped at this point.

Here's the relevant code:

```
import * as h from "../TestHelper";
import { RequestHook } from "testcafe";

const CLIENT = "san-fran";

class SetCorrectRefererHeader extends RequestHook {
  constructor(requestFilterRules, responseEventOptions) {
    super(requestFilterRules, responseEventOptions);
  }

  async onRequest(e) {
    if (e.isAjax) {
      console.log("request event is", e);
      console.log("request options", e.requestOptions);
      console.log("requestInfo", e.requestInfo);
      console.log("_requestInfo", e._requestInfo);
      e.requestOptions.headers["Referer"] = `${h.getClientUrl(CLIENT)}`;
    }
  }

  async onResponse(e) {
    //console.log("response event is", e);
  }
}

const setCorrectReferer = new SetCorrectRefererHeader();

// using this test just to make sure hook works
test.requestHooks(setCorrectReferer)(`referer`, async t => {
  await t.navigateTo(`https://whatsmyreferer.com/`);

  await t.debug();
});
```

and this is what gets logged to my terminal from those logging statements when the ajax request is made:

```
{} request event is RequestEvent {
  requestFilterRule: RequestFilterRule {
    options: { url: /.*/, method: undefined, isAjax: undefined },
    id: 'HeKfTLWm3',
    isPredicate: false
  },
  _requestContext: null,
  _requestInfo: {
    requestId: 'if97H3RMU',
    userAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.88 Safari/537.36',
    url: 'https://www.google-analytics.com/j/collect?v=1&_v=j96&a=719088816&t=pageview&_s=1&dl=https%3A%2F%2Fwhatsmyreferer.com%2F&ul=en-us&de=UTF-8&dt=What%27s%20My%20Referer%20%3F&sd=24-bit&sr=3360x1890&vp=1200x1668&je=0&_u=IEBAAEABAAAAAC~&jid=661957536&gjid=1633557977&cid=2140452944.1649960915&tid=UA-36499947-1&_gid=1676613645.1649960915&_r=1&_slc=1&z=1607123390',
    method: 'post',
    isAjax: true,
    headers: {
      host: 'www.google-analytics.com',
      connection: 'keep-alive',
      'content-length': 0,
      'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.88 Safari/537.36',
      'content-type': 'text/plain',
      accept: '*/*',
      origin: 'https://whatsmyreferer.com',
      'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
      'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9'
    },
    body: <Buffer >,
    sessionId: '5COBqXww8'
  },
  id: 'uUuQv4azM',
  setMock: [AsyncFunction (anonymous)]
}
{} request options undefined
{} requestInfo undefined
{} _requestInfo {
  requestId: 'if97H3RMU',
  userAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.88 Safari/537.36',
  url: 'https://www.google-analytics.com/j/collect?v=1&_v=j96&a=719088816&t=pageview&_s=1&dl=https%3A%2F%2Fwhatsmyreferer.com%2F&ul=en-us&de=UTF-8&dt=What%27s%20My%20Referer%20%3F&sd=24-bit&sr=3360x1890&vp=1200x1668&je=0&_u=IEBAAEABAAAAAC~&jid=661957536&gjid=1633557977&cid=2140452944.1649960915&tid=UA-36499947-1&_gid=1676613645.1649960915&_r=1&_slc=1&z=1607123390',
  method: 'post',
  isAjax: true,
  headers: {
    host: 'www.google-analytics.com',
    connection: 'keep-alive',
    'content-length': 0,
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.88 Safari/537.36',
    'content-type': 'text/plain',
    accept: '*/*',
    origin: 'https://whatsmyreferer.com',
 ✖ referer

   1) undefinedAn unhandled error occurred in the "onRequest" method of the "SetCorrectRefererHeader" class:
      
      TypeError: Cannot read property 'headers' of undefined

      Browser: Chrome 100.0.4896.88 / macOS 10.15.7
```

I feel like I have to be missing something, but I can't figure out what...

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce your case in Testcafe (version 1.18.5) and Chrome (version 100.0.4896.88). Make sure that you use the latest versions.